# Saving a new child to an existing parent using nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I'm using nested attributes to create different childs using one create action, the first time it creates the parent everything works as it should, but when the parent is used again then there is a unique constraint error since it is trying to create a new parent record instead of using the old one to add the new child. Question is if this is working as intended and if it is, how could I fix the code so that I don't have to check for each association to create the record

View

```
<%= form_with model: @email, method: :post do |t| %>
  <%= t.text_field  :name, placeholder: 'Nombre'%>
  <%= t.text_field  :email, placeholder: 'Correo'%>
  <%= t.text_field  :phone, placeholder: 'Celular'%>
  <%= t.fields_for :credit_emails do |credit| %>
  <%= credit.text_field :amount, placeholder: '¿Cuánto necesitas?' %>
  <%= credit.text_field :pay_time, placeholder: '¿En cuánto puedes pagar?' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= t.fields_for :card_emails do |card| %>
    <%= card.text_field :content, placeholder: '¿Qué es lo que más te llamó la atención de la tarjeta?' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= t.fields_for :contact_emails do |contact| %>
    <%= contact.text_field :subject, placeholder: 'Asunto' %>
    <%= contact.text_field :content, placeholder: 'Escríbenos tu mensaje' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= t.submit 'Envío' %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```rb
class EmailsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @email = Email.create(email_params)
  end

  def email_params
    params.require(:email).permit(:name, :email, :phone, 
      contact_emails_attributes: %i[content subject],
      credit_emails_attributes: %i[amount pay_time], 
      card_emails_attributes: %i[content])
  end
end
```

```rb
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  before_action :email_create, except: %i[new simulator]

  def new
    @title = 'homepage'
  end

  def credit
    @email.credit_emails.build
  end

  def card
    @email.card_emails.build
  end

  def contact_page
    @email.contact_emails.build
  end

  def simulator; end
end
```

Model

```rb
class Email < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :card_emails, foreign_key: :email_id, inverse_of: :email, autosave: true
  has_many :contact_emails, foreign_key: :email_id, inverse_of: :email, autosave: true
  has_many :credit_emails, foreign_key: :email_id, inverse_of: :email, autosave: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :card_emails
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_emails
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :credit_emails

  before_save :downcase_email

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 20 }
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :phone, presence: true, format: { with: /\d[0-9]+/ }, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 10 }

  def downcase_email
    email.downcase!
  end
end
```

Thank you for your help and I hope this helps other people

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation that posting the form multiple times should just create the nested records is completely wrong. `POST /emails` should be expected to create a new record every time. If you want to allow the user to create nested records for an existing email this should be a request to `PATCH /emails/:id`.

You can fix this by removing the `method: :post` option:

```
# make this into a partial so that it can be reused
<%= form_with model: @email do |t| %>
```

And by setting up an edit/update action:

```
class EmailsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_email, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # PATCH /emails/1
  def update
    if @email.update(email_params)
      redirect_to @email
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # POST /emails
  def create
    @email = Email.new(email_params)
    if @email.save 
      redirect_to edit_email_path(@email)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_email
    @email = Email.find(params[:id])
  end

  def email_params
     params.require(:email)
           .permit(
              :name, :email, :phone, 
              contact_emails_attributes: %i[id content subject],
              credit_emails_attributes: %i[id amount pay_time], 
              card_emails_attributes: %i[id content]
           )
  end
end
```

```
# app/views/emails/edit.html.erb
<h1>Edit email</h1>
<% render partial: 'form' %>
```

As for the nested records - `fields_for` will output a hidden `id` input for each nested record if the record has been persisted. But if you don't whitelist the id a new record will be created every time instead of updating the exisiting record.

You should also consider splitting this into multiple nested routes instead of a single monster endpoint.

Comment: I may have mislead you with partial information, I don't want all of the nested attributes forms to show, only the ones in the corresponding page. Maybe I misunderstood the use of nested attributes in forms. Also when the update fails it shows all the other records which is not needed. Just what the user was doing so it can be corrected

Comment: Yes it sounds like you're confused about what nested attributes are used for. They are used to create / edit nested records together with the parent record. If you just want to create records that belong to something else on their own you want to create separate nested routes, controllers and forms for an endpoint like for example `POST /countries/:country_id/cities`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do either. It looks somewhat like Multiple Table Inheritance. And you might want to just use inheritance in your controller together with partials to make controllers for the different types of emails.